# making a method that adds a generic layer to a scene

Tags: ios, background, cocos2d-iphone, scroll

I have made backgrounds for my game, each in their respective layer classes. I also created an enum of each of the various layers. I want to make a method that allows me to create instance of a background layer (general) to the scene. The idea behind this is I want to be able to have instances of the background so I can scroll through different types. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

you mean having a factory class for building layers or scenes?
if that's not what you mean try to articulate better you question as is not very clear

a SceneFactory can have something like

```
- (CCScene *) sceneOfType:(enum SceneType) type {
   switch(type){
       case type1:
           return [[Scene1 alloc] init];
       case type2:
           return [[Scene2 alloc] init];
   }           
}
```